# Android: open flash video stream on fullscreen

Tags: android, flash, video, stream, fullscreen

I would like to know if theres any way to open a webview with a stream flash video on fullscreen.

Right now ive the link of the page. This page has some stuff and a flash video. So i wonder if it would be posible to open the webview only with the stream video. In fullscreen or focused on it, without seing anything else. I mean, only the webview with the video, or the whole page, but with the view focused and zoomed so that i could just see the video.

Also, since there could get different kind of web pages, the video could come on different ways. But for now, would be enough to know if it would be posible to open it on fullscreen.

Thanks.

Comment: have you tried setting stage.displayStage = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN? Remeber to add allowFullScreen="true" to the html params. Not tested but this is how I would approach it.

Answer (score 0):

This may apply to the Android platform, but I think that for web-browser Flash Player - in order to go to full-screen, it requires a user action (like a button click) to initiate the transition.  This means that the SWF cannot by itself initiate the transition.
I suspect that it applies to Android too.  Are you writing and AIR app or a browser-based webpage.